# Loading NSBundle files iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle

I am attempting to load an executable file from a bundle stored in the apps documents directory. I can create the NSBundle successfully and read the info.plist but whenever I try to load the bundle with `[NSBundle load]` I always get a similar error no matter how I try to load the bundle:

> Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x.....  (not loaded)" or, when using an NSError "The bundle "${PRODUCT_NAME}" couldn't be loaded because its executable couldn't be located

The bundle contains two items, 1) info.plist and 2) Obj-c class header and implementation. I have edited the info.plist to change the Principal class name.

I first copy the bundle into the iPhone simulators documents directory then run the following code after a button press to load the bundle.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestBundle.bundle"];

NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath: file];
[myBundle load];
```

I understand that you are not supposed to load executables after run time but I have seen a couple of articles/ comments from people who are able to do it, at least on a simulator.

I would basically like to know why i get this error and how to fix it (if possible).

Thanks

Comment: How are you building the bundle? If it actually has headers & implementation files (i.e. `.m` files) you would have to compile them first to an executable.

Comment: @JesseRusak I was following someone else's example where they crate an OSX Bundle then change the Base SDK to iOS. I then just copied the folder to the documents directory of the simulator. If you would like to look at the example it can be found here: link in the bit about plugins. He has an example project but I get the same error using that. –  FusionReactor 7 mins ago

Comment: you can't load code on iOS that way-- well maybe with iOS8 but I don't think so either

Comment: and just h and m files won't make an app on any os :/ you need to compile it

Comment: @Daij-Djan thanks, I have also tried using the compiled code from the build folder but I still got the same message.

Comment: I have solved my initial problem of not finding an executable, I was copying the wrong file into the documents directory. The app is now executing external code. But only on the simulator for now.

Comment: you are targeting ios8 then? or a jailbroken phone?

Comment: oh and as an idea. try `loadAndReturnError` method to get more info

Comment: @Daij-Djan cheers for the advice, i am using ios 8 but it is possible on any OS version whilst running in debug mode or on a simulator. I dont expect the technique to work on a device not running in debug mode because of code signing issues. But I will see where I get to